# Create Dynamic Grid with Bootstrap to show video

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a video chat using Bootstrap and javascript. Right now for every person in the video chat there is an equal sized "view window" of their video stream. After two people join you must scroll down to see the next person. What I'm wanting is a way, with bootstrap, to start out with one cell, with dimensions for example of 400x400px filling the entire grid. If another person joins the chat, it would resize both videos to be equal size, so 200x200px. Then if yet another joined it would resize them all again to 100x100px.

I am using panel panel-default right now so there isn't much to show for code, I'm new to bootstrap and haven't been able to find a way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let you start with

```
<div class="col-xs-8 video-panel"></div>
```

When one person join you need to add one more div and update the class of the previous div. You can access the previous divs with selector

```
".video-panel"
```

Then you can add new div with following classes:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 video-panel"></div>
```

Final html will look like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 video-panel"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4 video-panel"></div>
```

Similarly, if one more person join, then update the classes to col-xs-2 for selector `.video-panel` and then add one more `div` element with the classes `col-xs-2 video-panel`

Final html will look like this

```
<div class="col-xs-2 video-panel"></div>
<div class="col-xs-2 video-panel"></div>
<div class="col-xs-2 video-panel"></div>
```

Updating the classes and adding new html tags you need to use javascript. Add for `col-xs-*` classes to work you have to add reference of twitter bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try tonight. Looks simple enough, I knew I had to be complicating things.

Comment: Sorry, I was pulled off for another project. Yes, the solution did work. I ran into other issues with the videos not staying within the bounds of the columns but I believe I have it all worked out now.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap grids. You can dynamically change the grid class according to number of videos

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/